# How to compile java files in netbeans faster?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
ant -f D:\\myJAVA\\javasbc -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build
Updating property file: D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\classes
Created dir: D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\classes\META-INF
Copying 1 file to D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\classes\META-INF
Created dir: D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\empty
Created dir: D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 98 source files to D:\myJAVA\javasbc\build\classes
```

Compiling stops here for almost a half hour. Is it that Netbeans cannot compile bigger files efficiently?

Comment: It's not an issue with Netbeans, if you tried to do this from the command line, you'd have the same problem.  You could try using the "Compile on Save" option, which would make it faster to run from within Netbeans as it wouldn't try and rebuild ALL the source files each time you run, but when you do a clean and build, you would still have the same problem.  Or application is up to 12 minutes for a full build :P

Comment: I need the jar file after compiling. The "Compile on Save" is already checked. Is there another way to get the jar file?

Comment: Nope, you will eventually need to "build" the project.

Comment: If i will use "build" not "clean and build" it will produce jar file? It has the same result?

Comment: I think if you have compile on save enabled, you have to use clean and build...been a while since I've done without it

Comment: I've tried to use "build" but it says its already compiled on save. Netbeans recommends to use "clean and build". Same results in compiling like posted above.

Comment: If you're not getting any benefits form compile and save, you could turn it off, but this means it will try and build the project each time its run

Comment: Yeah your right. But my problem is,  the compiling of the application is too long, and i don't know when it will finished. I need the jar file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you're just going to have to sit through it.  The only way you "might" make it faster is to break the application down into smaller chunks and rely on the output of those "sub" projects as "libraries" to your main project.  This then runs you into issues of dependency management

Comment: You must have humungous source files, or a very slow PC. I have 179 source files in one projects and it only takes 30 seconds to compile and build the JAR file, which is 30MB.

Comment: After 130 minutes, I've got the jar file. I've read some posts/blogs some said the problem is on JDK. I'm using JDK 8. Thanks @MadProgrammer for your opinions.

Comment: It won't be the JDK. My 30 seconds has been pretty constant with all of 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, and 1.8. More probably some local condition in your computer. I had an incompetently written virus scanner installed once that had this effect: it scanned every newly created file, which is absurd.

Comment: There was a bug in earlier JDK 8 builds that would cause a slow compile on certain classes: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043253?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

Comment: Do i need to update my jdk, @a_horse_with_no_name?

Comment: Thanks @EJP, but i dont have any anti virus/virus scanner in my computer. Which version of JDK fixed this issue, @a_horse_with_no_name? Thanks.

Comment: Guys I install latest version of JDK and compiling time last in 1 minute.